# How to get values in a column of a DataTable?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication, datatable

I have Login page in my Asp.NET project, what i want basically is get the row of a column of a query that returns the i_idficha, contrasena and the **s_nombre**. The column called **s_nombre** will be saved in a variable SESSION. Here's what i have:

```
Protected Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.USUARIO.i_idficha, dbo.CONTRASENA_USUARIO.s_contrasena, dbo.USUARIO.s_nombre FROM dbo.USUARIO INNER JOIN dbo.CONTRASENA_USUARIO ON dbo.USUARIO.i_idficha = dbo.CONTRASENA_USUARIO.i_ficha WHERE i_idficha = @ficha AND s_contrasena = @pass", cn)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ficha", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtUser.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPass.Text
    cn.Open()
    Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim table As New DataTable()

    adp.Fill(table)
    Dim nombre = table.Rows("s_nombre").ToString()
    If table.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
        If CheckBox1.Checked Then
            Response.Cookies("FICHA").Value = txtUser.Text
            Response.Cookies("CONTRASENA").Value = txtPass.Text

            Response.Cookies("FICHA").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10)
            Response.Cookies("CONTRASENA").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10)
        Else
            Response.Cookies("FICHA").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
            Response.Cookies("CONTRASENA").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
        End If

        Session("NOMBRE") = nombre
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx")
    Else
        Panel1.Visible = True
    End If

End Sub
```

What i did here was to declare a variable called **nombre** that is equal to

> table.Rows("s_nombre").ToString()

And save it in a variable **SESSION("NOMBRE")** but doesn't work.

This is the error:

> The input string does not have the correct format

This is my code-behind for the Default.aspx:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Session("FICHA") <> Nothing Then
        Label1.Text = "Bienvendio <i aria-hidden='true' class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></i> " & Session("NOMBRE").ToString()
    Else
        Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx")
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub linkBtnLogOut_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles linkBtnLogOut.Click
    Session("FICHA") = Nothing
    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx")
End Sub
```

How to save the column called **s_nombre** of my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that table.Rows(x) expects the row index, not the column string. So it should be:

```
Dim nombre = table.Rows(0)("s_nombre").ToString()
```

Comment: Hi another error ocurred:

>There is no row at position 0

Comment: This means the DataTable is empty. Move that line of code inside to be inside the "If table.Rows.Count <> 0 Then" if statement to avoid this error. Then check your SELECT statement to make sure it is returning data.

Comment: Hi again, i move that line inside my IF statement but the program does nothing, not redirect to Default.aspx, i will edit my question to add my code-behind for the Default.aspx.
The SELECT query returns data.

Answer (score 0):

i want to post my answer, i solved because i forgot write

```
SESSION("FICHA") = txtUser.Text
```

Then my code for the Login would:

```
Protected Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
           Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.USUARIO.i_idficha, dbo.CONTRASENA_USUARIO.s_contrasena, dbo.USUARIO.s_nombre FROM dbo.USUARIO INNER JOIN dbo.CONTRASENA_USUARIO ON dbo.USUARIO.i_idficha = dbo.CONTRASENA_USUARIO.i_ficha WHERE i_idficha = @ficha AND s_contrasena = @pass", cn)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ficha", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtUser.Text
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPass.Text
    cn.Open()
    Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    adp.Fill(table)
    If table.Rows.Count <> 0 Then

        If CheckBox1.Checked Then
            Response.Cookies("FICHA").Value = txtUser.Text
            Response.Cookies("CONTRASENA").Value = txtPass.Text

            Response.Cookies("FICHA").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10)
            Response.Cookies("CONTRASENA").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10)
        Else
            Response.Cookies("FICHA").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
            Response.Cookies("CONTRASENA").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
        End If
        Dim nombre = table.Rows(0)(2).ToString()
        Session("FICHA") = txtUser.Text
        Session("NOMBRE") = nombre
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx")
    Else
        Panel1.Visible = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Thank You @Aki